# How to add a piece of code in function

Tags: functions

On the function below, after `echo '</span>';`, I want to add  this a piece of code:

```
&nbsp;<a href="<?php $key="link"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" target="_blank">Images Source</a>
```

But I dunno how to do it, any suggestions on how to do this?

```
//echo '<div class="pull-left">';
        echo in_array( 'date',$meta_info ) ? sprintf( '<span class="post-meta-info posted-on">' . apply_filters('yt_icon_date_time', '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>') . ' %1$s</span>',
            $time_string
        ) : '';
        if( in_array( 'comments',$meta_info ) ){
            echo '<span class="post-meta-info with-cmt">' . apply_filters('yt_icon_comment', '<i class="fa fa-comments"></i>') . ' ';
                comments_popup_link( __( '0 Comments', 'theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'theme' ));
            echo '</span>';
        }



    //echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( in_array( 'comments',$meta_info ) ){
            $key="link";
            echo '<span class="post-meta-info with-cmt">' . apply_filters('yt_icon_comment', '<i class="fa fa-comments"></i>') . ' ';
                comments_popup_link( __( '0 Comments', 'theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'theme' ));
            echo '</span>';
            echo '&nbsp;<a href="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true) .'" target="_blank">Images Source</a>' . "\n";
        }
```

Try this code once. I modified the code with your supplied content.

Comment: what about the code href="<?php $key="link"   look like missing on your modified code

Comment: no it is not missing. I assigned it at top `$key="link";`

Comment: ok, didn't see it,but when I added link on custom field with value http://www.yahoo.com it doesnt work. the image source show the single post link, instead of value http://www.yahoo.com

Comment: hmm...if you're using the function for meta value then you'll assign the `global $post;` inside the function. Then `$post->ID` will work in get_post_meta function.

Comment: so how to add global $post; ? would you mind to explain it ,I am still learning btw, and thanks for the help

Comment: are you adding the code in single.php or index.php file? or you are using a function to display the post info? if you are using the function then `global $post;` is required. otherwise `get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true)` would be `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $key, true)` . Also you'll double check the meat key name ("link").

Comment: that code above is from my theme-functions.php and actualy I just want to add that a piece of code on my single.php but when I checked my index.php,that code is display too, so I think I have to look on single.php because I just need on the single.php only